# Passing JsonResponse data (from Django views) as a url parameter in Javascript is not working

Tags: javascript, python, django, jinja2, paypal-sandbox

I am making a website in django that has paypal client side payment integration. My payment works fine but after payment is completed, i send the delivery data to a django views function using fetch API and views function returns me a JsonResponse.
I am trying to pass data from that response as a url parameter to another django view which will render a success page about the order with a few details in it.

The problem I encounter is as follows:

**NoReverseMatch at /product-details/payment**

**Reverse for 'order_successful' with keyword arguments '{'DATA': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['order_successful/(?P[^/]+)$']**

here is code for *checkout.html* which is calling *paymentComplete.views*

```
<script>
function completeOrder(){
            var url = "{% url 'paymentComplete' %}"
            
            fetch(url, {
              method: 'POST',
              headers:{
                  'Content-type': 'application/json',
                  'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
              },
              body:JSON.stringify({'prodID': prodId, 'quantity': quantityBought, 'bill': total, 'fName': fName, 'lName': lName, 'apt': apt, 'street': street, 'city': city, 'state': state, 'zipcode': zipcode, 'country': country, 'email': email, 'phone': phone})
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then((data) => {
                  console.log('Success ', data);
                  console.log(typeof data);
                  alert('Transaction Completed');
                  window.location.href = "{% url 'order_successful' DATA=data %}"
            })
          }
</script>
```

following is code for *paymentComplete.views*

```
def paymentComplete(request):
    body = json.loads(request.body)

    prod_ID = int(body['prodID'])
    prod_Qt_bought = int(body['quantity'])
    bill_paid = str(body['bill'])

    #loading product from store
    prod_from_store = Product.objects.get(id=prod_ID)
    #previous product quantity    
    previous_Qt = int(prod_from_store.left)

    newLeft = previous_Qt - prod_Qt_bought

    print(body)


    return JsonResponse(prod_from_store.color, safe=False)
```

the views function being called with

> window.location.href = "{% url 'order_successful' DATA=data %}"
> is *orderSuccessful.views* and its code is as follows:

```
def order_successful(request, DATA):
    print(request)
    return render(request, 'order_successful.html', {'DATA':DATA})
```

and my application urls.py for reference is :

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('all-products', views.all_products, name='all-products'),
    path('request-a-quote', views.request_quote, name = 'RequestQuote'),
    path('contact-us', views.contact_us, name='ContactUs'),
    path('about', views.about, name='about'),
    path('product-details/<int:ID>', views.prod_temp, name='prod_temp'),
    path('ContactUs', views.ContactUs, name='contact-us'),
    path('calcQuote', views.calcQuote, name='calculate-quote'),
    path('product-details/purchase', views.purchase, name='purchase'),
    path('product-details/payment', views.payment, name='payment'),
    path('product-details/paymentComplete', views.paymentComplete, name='paymentComplete'),
    path('order_successful/<str:DATA>', views.order_successful, name='order_successful'),
]
```

It works fine when i pass a harcoded string instead of data in the following line in *checkout.html* and throws the previously mentioned error of NoReverseMatch

> window.location.href = "{% url 'order_successful' DATA=data %}"

Help and guidance is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You say, it works fine when you send a hard-coded string. So, why are you trying to send the response as a JSON object instead of a string? You are parsing the response into a JSON object, when you use `response.json()`. So, JSONstringify the data and then try it.

Comment: Thanks for a quick response. Where should i do JSONstringify on the data? I tried it and now the error is
NoReverseMatch at /product-details/payment

Reverse for 'order_successful' with keyword arguments '{'DATA': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['order_successful/(?P<DATA>[^/]+)$']

I performed following changes in checkout.html file
temp=JSON.stringify(data);
window.location.href = "{% url 'order_successful' DATA=temp %}"

other than passing hardcoded values, it is also working when i pass it prod.color which is a jinja variable being used in this page.

Comment: when i do console.log(typeof data), the output is string

Comment: @Geshode problem solved by doing the following:

`var temp = JSON.stringify(data)`
`window.location.href = "{% url 'order_successful' DATA='123' %}".replace("123", this.temp)`

I don't understand why it worked like this. Probably something to do with value of data not being available at the time or passing value of a js variable to a python code. It would be very nice if someone can explain why it works now with this modification? 
Thanks!